# Printing a 2d character array

Tags: java, printing, multidimensional-array, arrays

Printing out a 2d character array is not difficult, but the way I need to do it seems to be.

My current goal is initialize a 2d character array, such that every cell contains '-'. This must be done within the constructor method. Below is what I have thus far.

```
public class GameOfLife {

public final int MAX_SIZE = 12;

// instance variables
private char [][] current = new char[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
private char [][] next    = new char[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  /**
   * Constructor for objects of class GameOfLife.  
   * Initializes the current array to '-'.
   */

    public void GameOfLife() {
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
            for ( int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++){
                current [i][j] = '-';
            }
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
            for ( int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++){
                sb.append(current[i][j]);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            sb.append("\n"); // add new line
        } 

        return sb.toString(); // convert to String and return
      }
    }`
```

I know how to properly print it if it were just to be printed within this method; however, I must use the "GameOfLife" constructor in the following way. This next code is in the driver class, which is called "gameoflifedriver".

```
   // Create a GameOfLife object
    GameOfLife lifeGame = new GameOfLife();
    System.out.print(lifeGame);
```

The problem that I am having is that the lifeGame will not print, and an odd error message occurs - GameOfLife@5d3892b3. I know there are ways to print it, but I cannot change any of the code in the driver class - so all of the edits must be in the GameOfLife code. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to override `toString()` method in `GameOfLife` class.  The output you're getting comes from the one inherited from `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `toString()` method. Also you could use a `StringBuilder`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        for ( int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++){
            sb.append(current[i][j]);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append("\n"); // add new line
    } 

    return sb.toString(); // convert to String and return
}
```

Then you can print this representation with:

```
GameOfLife lifeGame = new GameOfLife();
System.out.print(lifeGame);
```

**Note:** Constructors *don't have a return type*, so you shouldn't declare it with return type `void`:

```
public GameOfLife() {/* Constructor body */}
```

Comment: Is there a simple reason as to why the toString() method must be overridden? Also, when I try to implement the Override, an error occurs stating that a semicolon must be placed in front of the toString method.

Comment: Because then, you can simply print a representation of an instance of `GameOfLife` with `System.out.print(gameOfLifeInstance);`

Comment: Ah, ok. When trying to implement the Override, an error occurs stating that a semicolon is expeted after toString, and I do not know why. Is overriding the only way?

Comment: `@Override` is not the problem. The error may be somewhere else. Try to checking your code meticulously.

Comment: I had no syntax errors before placing in the Override code. Should the Override code be inside the GameOfLife method? That is where I have it.

Comment: Yes. Try deleting the `@Override`, you have any error?

Comment: When I delete the @Override, the public String toString(){} becomes the start of an illegal expression.

Comment: Can you edit your post **adding** your current code? I mean, the whole class.

Comment: Okay, you are putting the `toString()` method **inside** the "constructor". It must be out of the constructor. Also, make sure you delete that `void` as I mentioned in my answer above. Make sure your brackets `{}` matches. It looks like you have a missing one.

Comment: Thanks Christian! It is now working very well. Before this I was not aware of the @Override function. Just to clarify, is there no other way to do this other than to Override the toString method?

Comment: It's not an @Override function, it's an [annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html). And yes, there is another way. Just print, using nested `for` with `System.out.print` inside. But this would be done **out** of the class `GameOfLife`. You can also create a method inside the class, something like `public void printGameOfLife() { ... }`

Comment: I know how to print the proper grid; however, the constraint I am under is that I cannot create another method. I must be able to use the GameOfLife constructor method, which must then be able to be printed in the driver class. It seems that I must be able to convert the 2d character array to a String from within the constructor, is this doable? Also, I am a student of Industrial/Systems Engineering as well, living in Seattle. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to convert it to a `String` inside the constructor. It is possible if you create an instance member, let's say `String representation`, and you store the `String` there, but you will have to make the computations in the constructor. **Note** that constructors are usually used to initialize members. Read about what a constructor is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Class GameOfLife constructor should not have void return type (java rule).
And the toString() method is good to implement.